# React Native - Search an array off Object using react hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have an array off Object inside a variable named data. 
The array looks like this:

```
const data = [
      {
        "id": "0.804802585702977",
        "value": "Bar",
      },
      {
        "id": "0.9359341974615858",
        "value": "Mar",
      },
      {
        "id": "0.4182922963461958",
        "value": "Naba",
      },
      {
        "id": "0.6132336648416628",
        "value": "Socerr",
      },
      {
        "id": "0.060587558948085984",
        "value": "Mall",
      },
    ]
```

I want to create a search bar to search all the value inside that array and if the search text is equal to the value inside that array the user will be able to see that value?
Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `filter` function to search/Sort data from Array. Please check following it may solve you problem.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, TextInput, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from "./components/AssetExample";

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from "react-native-paper";

const data = [
  {
    id: "0.804802585702977",
    value: "Bar",
  },
  {
    id: "0.9359341974615858",
    value: "Mar",
  },
  {
    id: "0.4182922963461958",
    value: "Naba",
  },
  {
    id: "0.6132336648416628",
    value: "Socerr",
  },
  {
    id: "0.060587558948085984",
    value: "Mall",
  },
];
export default function App() {
  let [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(data);

  function _searchFilterFunction(searchText, data) {
    let newData = [];
    if (searchText) {
      newData = data.filter(function(item) {
        const itemData = item.value.toUpperCase();
        const textData = searchText.toUpperCase();
        return itemData.includes(textData);
      });
      setFilteredData([...newData]);
    } else {
      setFilteredData([...data]);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Search Here.</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        placeholder="Search"
        placeholderTextColor="#9a73ef"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        onChangeText={(value) => {
          _searchFilterFunction(value, data);
        }}
      />
      {filteredData.map((item, index) => {
        return <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{item.value}</Text>;
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,

    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8,
  },
  input: {
    margin: 15,
    height: 40,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: "#7a42f4",
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
```